# Converting data from one format to another in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to convert this tree structure:

```
{
  "id":1,"name":"Corp.","emoji":"","parent_id":null,"children":
  [
    {"id":2,"name":"Food","emoji":"","parent_id":1,"children":[]},
    {"id":3,"name":"Canine+Therapy","emoji":"","parent_id":1,"children":
      [
        {"id":4,"name":"Massages","emoji":"","parent_id":3,"children":[]},
        {"id":5,"name":"Games","emoji":"","parent_id":3,"children":[]}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

to this format:

```
[
        [ 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Corp.', 'emoji' => '' ,'parent_id' => null ],
        [ 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Food', 'emoji' => '',  'parent_id' => 1 ],
        [ 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Canine Therapy', 'emoji' => '', 'parent_id' => 1 ],
        [ 'id' => 4, 'name' => 'Massages', 'emoji' => '', 'parent_id' => 3 ],
        [ 'id' => 5, 'name' => 'Games', 'emoji' => '', 'parent_id' => 3 ],
]
```

Any idea on how to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function like this:

```
function collapse($tree, &$collapsed = []) {
    $tree = clone $tree;
    $collapsed[] = $tree;
    foreach ($tree->children as $child) {
        collapse($child, $collapsed);
    }
    unset($tree->children);
    return $collapsed;
}

$new = collapse($tree);
```

Note that the `$collapsed` variable that holds the result must be passed by reference for this to work. Each time the function is called the current node is added to the result array, then each of its children is added recursively, then the children property is removed.

`clone` is necessary in the first line to prevent this function from destroying the original tree when it unsets children. If you don't need the original tree you can omit that.

Working example: https://3v4l.org/U6mHs